# How to make a HTTP request to a XMLRPC server from Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, server

I try to make this request with the HttpClient of Angular, but i do not if I was making the formatting in the right way.

```
 authUser() {
    var json = {
      methodName: 'authenticate',
      params: {
          db: this.auth.db
          user: this.auth.user,
          password: this.auth.password
      }
    }
    var headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-type': 'text/xml'
    })
    var xml = JsonToXML.parse('methodCall', json) 
    console.log(xml);
    this.http.post(this.auth.url, xml, {
      headers: headers
    }).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

I need to make a request like this but from Ionic Angular

```
import xmlrpclib
import ssl

url = 'https://demo.demo.mx'
db = 'demo.dbdemo.mx'
user = 'demo@demo.com'
password = '123'

common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url), verbose=False, use_datetime=True,context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
print(common)
# Consultar uid de usuario (autenticacion)
uid = common.authenticate(db, user, password, {})
print(uid)

models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url), verbose=False, use_datetime=True,context=ssl._create_unverified_context())

lead_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'crm.lead', 'create', [{
    'name': 'Nombre del lead',
    'contact_name': 'Nombre del contacto',
    'type': 'lead',
    'email': 'correo@demo.com',
    'phone': '1234567890',
    'mobile': '1234567890'
}])

print(lead_id)
```

I also tried with some NPM libraries like xmlrpc and davexmlrpc but the project just did not compile.
I wonder if this is possible, or I need to make a microservice to handle the HTTP request and send it to the XMLRPC server.